# How can I run msbuild from a windows service?

Tags: msbuild, windows-services

I'm trying to run this batch file from a windows service (running as my own user) and msbuild doesn't work. Running it directly however, works. I'm getting a buch of "The handle is invalid" on stderr from I presume vcvarsall.bat.

```
rem Load compilation environment
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
rem Load the All Solutions.sln program
msbuild "C:\AutoBuildCheckout\Other Projects\All Projects\All Projects.sln"
pause
```

I'm confused. Anyone have any suggestions?

-Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services in Windows Vista and higher run in a separate desktop, and therefore don't have access to `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. (Services can no longer 'interact with desktop'; you'll notice that option is missing from the services applet in Control Panel.)

EDIT: After the comments below... A service IMO is the wrong solution. There are continuous integration products that manage this for you, like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) or [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net); I'm sure there are many others. See also [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) at Wikipedia for more info.

Comment: I can get the standard error and output using Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput and then reading it using a StreamReader. Anyways, I have a master solution file with what will eventually have a few dozen projects in them, each of them depending on some core library projects. I'm using a post commit hook script to send a command to the service to attempt to build the master solution. Then, if the exitcode of the batch file is not zero I send the error message and an email to whoever broke the build.

Comment: I opted for a service initially so that only one build can be running at a time. I also want to use this service to automatically run test suites someday.

Comment: You might be able to connect to stdin and stdout, but you're not cmd.exe, which is what your batch file uses. Your reasons don't make sense to me, either; executing the build via a service doesn't prevent more than one build executing, and there are other ways to automatically run test suites. You should be looking at pre- and post-build events in MSBuild (post build could automatically run the tests, for instance). A service seems totally inappropriate to me, but that's just my opinion, and you know what those are worth. :)

Comment: To clarify: You may be getting stdin and stdout handles, but they're not the user desktop handles, which is what cmd.exe is using for output; that's why you're getting the errors from the batch file. The service runs in a totally separate desktop from the logged in user.

Comment: sorry, i'm probably unclear. The service is running on the subversion server. when someone commits something the to the server this service needs to check to see that what they committed doesn't break the build. It will also check someday to see that all the tests still run, maybe nightly.

Comment: aha. I didn't even know those tools existed. I didn't even know it was called 'continuous integration'. I was just sick and tired of manually  checking I didn't break the build.

Comment: Using teamcity now, I retired my own personal autobuilder (even though it worked)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to just not call vcvarsall.bat. Instead I'm directly summoning msbuild from where it sits in the windows directory. So I got around the problem without really knowing the solution.